# Issue in loading data to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

There is an issue in loading data to bigquery with error :

> "com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Invalid schema update. Field esb_shipping has changed type from STRING to INTEGER "

we use the loadJob to load data to bigquery using csv , this data type mismatch issue was observed in running state where we have not changed  the schema of the dataset nor there is any change in the export file which was previously used to load data to bigquery.

i tried to load data to bigquery but the load job gets failed expecting it to be success

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue and got an answer from the BigQuery Engineering team to use a schema specification in the load statement as a workaround. So you might try to specify the schema in your load job, e.g. for me in the query statement, I needed to add **(ts TIMESTAMP, Event JSON)**:

```
LOAD DATA into dataset.test (ts TIMESTAMP, Event JSON) FROM FILES ( format = 'JSON', uris = ['gs://bucket_name/json_debug_example*.json']);
```